# AVAssetWriter with images VS a set of images

Tags: ios, nsdata, avassetwriter

I am working on an iphone application that needs to send some images over the internet...

If I have a set of images that were frames of a video and I need to send this images over the internet...

I have 2 options in mind, send them as just they are (images), or to put them together with AVAssetWriter to become a video, and send the single video before sending over.

Which of the 2 options will have a bigger amount of data send over? Does AVAssetWriter compress the images (since they are similar) as I write them into a movie format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending the images as a movie will be smaller, because AVAssetWriter will use the frame similarities to aid compression (unless you set all i frames, which is functionally equivalent to sending your set of pictures).